# How can I assign an alias for a foreign key variable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a field in a model referencing a foreign key:

```
class InvitationToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitation_token_accesses
end
```

When I reference it, I need to code it like this:

```
invitation_token.invitation_token_accesses
```

whereas I'd like to just say:

```
invitation_token.accesses
```

What is the incantation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
has_many :accesses, :class => "InvitationTokenAccess"
```

Comment: I believe that _:class_ should be _:class_name_